# How to add formatting to this basic code (bold, H1, and center)

Tags: javascript, html, format

I'm not really a html javascript programmer, so I need some handholding.
I found a snip of code that I can plug into my website, but I'd like to add formatting.
I'm trying to display the current date (which this does), but I'd also like it to be H1, Bold, and Centered. I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, and thought maybe someone here could set me straight.

Here's the code snip (currently works), how do I format it?

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> var d=new Date(); var weekday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"); var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"); document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " "); document.write(d.getDate() + ". "); document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " "); document.write(d.getFullYear());</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3czsM.png)

Comment: Be wary of code that you find on the web that seems to "work". The code you've shown is how things were done 25+ years ago and is considered bad practice today. See my answer below for the modern approach.

Comment: Thank you, Scott... duly noted... LOL...

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished quite easily with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), but note that an `h1` should not be used because of the native styling that the browser will render it with. [`h1` is for document structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements). If you want bigger text, just style that as well:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page Title</title>
    <style>
      #date { font-weight:bold; text-align:center; font-size:1.1em; }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="date"></div>
   <script>
     var d = new Date(); 
     var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday"];
     var monthname = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

     document.getElementById("date").textContent = weekday[d.getDay()] + " " + monthname[d.getMonth()] +                                                        " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear();   
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even better of course would be to use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` or `toLocaleDateString()` with the appropriate options rather than the roll-your-own days of the week and month names thing...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, but I didn't want to change the one part of the OPs code that was technically correct and I wanted to show how to incorporate it into modern page structure.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Monkey, since I'm not really a Javascript/ html programmer, I don't understand your instructions. I programmed COBOL in the 80's so I can sort of puzzle my way thru simple stuff, but this advice is over my head. If I had more time, I'd study programming again... :) Thank you for reviewing it, though. Very kind of you.

Comment: @ScottMarcus,Thank you very very much, this is looking so much better!  

Follow up: this website is responsive... is there a way to make the size attribute responsive (and is that easy? )...  And I have no idea what an "em" is... but em 3 is looking good on the browser version.

Comment: An `em` is a unit that is relative to the font-size of the parent element. So, 1.1em would make the font size of the element that it's applied to 110% of the size of the parent element. To make the font responsive to page size, you could experiment with `vh` (viewport height) or `vw` (viewport width) units instead of em's.

Answer (score -1):

Just Add the tags you said like `<tag>...content...</tag>`

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    <strong>
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var weekday = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
      var monthname = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
      document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " ");
      document.write(d.getDate() + ". ");
      document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ");
      document.write(d.getFullYear());
    </script>
    <strong>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline scripts like this along with `document.write()` are 25+ year old techniques that are considered anti-patterns today. Additionally, `strong` should not be used purely for visual effect, it should be used for its semantic meaning.